# Google Voice displays "Testing" in place of a person's name (after they leave voicemail)?

Tags: google-voice

I recently setup Google Voice yet when a person leaves a voicemail instead of displaying the persons name or phone number it displays `Testing`.

How do I change this so it displays at least the persons number vs `Testing`?

Comment: Do you have a contact where the name is set to "Testing"?  Try changing it in Contacts.

Comment: I have no contact name "testing" Also no matter which number is called from the same thing displays.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I have never seen this, and I've been a GV user for ages.